# VCPKG Difference between windows, windows-static and other

Tags: vcpkg

What is the difference when I use

1. `vcpkg install <any package>:x64-windows`
2. `x64-windows-static`
3. `x64-windows-static-md`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
x64-windows:
VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE = dynamic
VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE = dynamic

x64-windows-static:
VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE = static
VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE = static

x64-windows-static-md:
VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE = static
VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE = dynamic
```

`VCPKG_LIBRARY_LINKAGE` Determines if a library/port is build as a static or dynamic library
`VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE` Determines if the static (`/MT(d)`) or dynamic (`/MD(d)`) CRT (C runtime) is used